# How to Run FFPlay from lua?

Tags: c++, windows, lua, ffmpeg

I have put together a windows C++ based lua shell application to test my media server. As part of this I need to launch FFPlay and have it play rtsp uri's. I have tried:

```
os.execute('ffplay.exe rtsp://uri')
```

And I have tried creating a C++ hook into my shell where I added a C++ function that then did:

```
system("ffplay.exe rtsp://uri");
```

Unfortunately in both cases FFPlay starts but doesn't create a window with the video in it. I am able to confirm that FFPlay is running by checking the list of processes running. Can explain how I can run FFPlay from my process and get it to create its video window on windows?

Thank you

Comment: does your command work from the command line as expected?

Comment: Yes it does, the difficulty is not that the command fails, as I mentioned FFPlay is started it's just that it fails to create a window. When I tested my code using VLC it worked so the failure to launch a window is FFPlay specific.

Comment: I just downloaded ffplay.exe and used os.execute() to connect to some random tv stream and it worked perfectly fine. Maybe try another ffplay buiild. Did you test other stream adresses or files? Is there no error output to some console?

Comment: What command did you try? I was simply running ffplay with against an rtsp url like you see above. I also am running ffplay version N-74462-g737aa90, which version do you have?

Comment: os.execute("A:\\ffplay.exe http://zdf0910-lh.akamaihd.net/i/dach10_v1@392872/master.m3u8?dw=0")
I downloaded a recent win64 build: https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win64/static/ffmpeg-20160425-git-9ac154d-win64-static.7z

Comment: Seems that my problem is specific to the fact that I am trying to play an rtsp stream, as soon as I try to play a static file or other source it works fine.